# ¿Qué le añaden "las pintas" al "cabrón"?

Tags: locuciones, vulgaridades

La primera acepción de [**cabrón**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6TAJjC0) es

> 1. adj. malson. coloq. Dicho de una persona, de un animal o de una cosa: Que hace malas pasadas o resulta molesto. U. t. c. s. Por antífrasis, u. t. en sent. ponder.

En el mismo artículo viene **cabrón con pintas** como

> 1. loc. adj. coloq. cabrón (‖ que hace malas pasadas). U. t. c. loc. sust. m. y f.

Aparentemente es exactamente la primera acepción de *cabrón*. ¿Qué le añade entonces el "*con pintas*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En ningún lugar se explica claramente el origen de esta expresión. En singular *pinta* puede significar lo mismo que *facha*, pero en plural la palabra remite a mancha o señal distintiva, como las que tienen los animales en su pelaje o plumaje.

De ser así, *con pintas* vendría a significar "marcado, distinguible, señalable", y por extensión, "inconfundible", como un animal cuyo patrón de pelaje o plumaje permite identificarlo. Y un *cabrón con pintas* sería un cabrón tan cabrón que cualquiera puede darse cuenta de que lo es, porque está marcado como tal. Para enfatizar más todavía el aspecto visual, algunas personas dicen incluso *cabrón con pintas coloradas*.

(Se me ocurre un paralelismo interesante entre esta expresión y una que refiere también a personas con defectos obvios y conocidos: *«Qué le hace una mancha más al tigre?»*.)

Más allá de este "razonamiento" la expresión puede haber evolucionado desde su significado original hasta ser un simple énfasis.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la expresión "un cabrón con pintas" es incompleta. Por lo que sé, la expresión original es "un cabrón con pintas en el lomo", lo cual deja más claro que al usarla estamos haciendo referencia a un animal que tiene manchas en la espalda.
Lo que no sé es a qué animal se refiere (lo lógico es que fuera un macho cabrío).

Answer (score 0):

Hay cuatro niveles de cabrón.
Cabroncete: Con poca maldad
Cabrón: Aumentamos su nivel maldad y frecuencia de cabronadas.
Cabrón con pintas: Sus cabronadas son sibilinas y no da puntada sin hilo
Cabronazo: Sus cabronadas son de  sicópata.

Todas pueden usarse de forma afectiva. El Español es divertidísimo.